# Perl compare operators and stringified "numbers"

Tags: string, perl, comparison, numbers, operators

I've been working a lot lately with perl, still I dont really know how `<,>,>=,=<, ne,gt`, etc.. on stringified "numbers", by "number" I mean something like: '1.4.5.6.7.8.0'

correct me If I'm wrong, the following returns true:

```
if ('1.4.5' > '8.7.8');
```

because both will be coerced to true (not an empty string).
but, how does `ne,gt`,etc string operators work on such numbers?

basically I'm trying to compare version numbers consisted of the following form:

```
1.3.4.0.2
```

I can make a numerical comparison of each digit, but before, I ranther want to know of the 
string comparing operators perform on such strings.

Thanks,

Comment: "1.4.5.6.7.8.0" is not a number. See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Scalar::Util)'s `looks_like_number`.

Comment: Actually, you said "number": «by "number" I mean something like: '1.4.5.6.7.8.0'». And then you used «`>`», which takes a *number* on each side, so my comment is appropriate even if you said "numbers".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First: Please `use warnings` all the time. You would have realized the following at once:

```
$ perl -wle 'print 1 unless "1.4.5" > "8.7.8"'
Argument "8.7.8" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at -e line 1.
Argument "1.4.5" isn't numeric in numeric gt (>) at -e line 1.
```

Perl v5.9.0 came distributed with [version](http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.97/lib/version.pod). And this module makes it very easy to compare version numbers:

```perl
use warnings;
use version;

my ($small, $large) =  (version->parse('1.4.5'), version->parse('8.7.8'));

print "larger\n"    if $small > $large;
print "smaller\n"   if $small < $large;
```

Answer (score 8):

A string comparison will only work if every number between the dots has the same length. A string comparison has no knowledge of *number* and will begin to compare dots and digits (as they are both characters in a string).

There a CPAN module that does exactly what you are looking for: [Sort::Versions](http://search.cpan.org/~edavis/Sort-Versions-1.5/Versions.pm)

Answer (score 3):

When you compare strings using numerical relation operators `<`, `>`, etc., Perl issues a warning if you `use warnings`. However, Perl will still attempt to convert the strings into numbers. If the string starts with digits, Perl will use these, otherwise the string equates to 0. In your example comparing  '1.4.5' and '8.7.8' has the same effect as comparing numbers 1.4 and 8.7.

But for `ne`, `gt`, etc. it really doesn't matter if your strings consist of numbers or anything else (including dots). Therefore:

```
print "greater" if '2.3.4' gt '10.1.2'  # prints 'greater' because '2' > '1' stringwise 
print "greater" if '02.3.4' gt '10.1.2' # prints nothing because '0' < '1' stringwise
```

Therefore you cannot use neither `>`, `<`, etc. nor `gt`, `lt`, etc. for version comparison, you have to choose different approach, as proposed in another answers, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure on the overhead of this, but you might try [`Sort::Naturally`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aNaturally). And particularly, the [`ncmp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort%3a%3aNaturally#The_ncmp_function) operator.

Answer (score 2):

As @tent pointed out, @SebastianStumpf's solution is close, but not quite right because:

```
>perl -Mversion -e 'my @n = ( "1.10", "1.9" ); print "$n[0] is " . ( version->parse($n[0]) > version->parse($n[1]) ? "larger" : "smaller" ) . " than $n[1]\n";'
1.10 is smaller than 1.9
```

Luckily this is easily solved following the hint in [version's documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jpeacock/version-0.9917/lib/version.pod#TYPES_OF_VERSION_OBJECTS):

> The leading 'v' is now strongly recommended for clarity, and will
>   throw a warning in a future release if omitted.

```
>perl -Mversion -e 'my @n = ( "1.10", "1.9" ); print "$n[0] is " . ( version->parse("v$n[0]") > version->parse("v$n[1]") ? "larger" : "smaller" ) . " than $n[1]\n";'
1.10 is larger than 1.9
```